# Question on non-parametric tests and comparing two groups across countries

Tags: hypothesis-testing, nonparametric, multiple-comparisons

I have a dataset with every election in various countries between 1900 and 2010.  There are about 300 elections but only between 20-40 elections in most countries.  I am trying to test whether electing a candidate A or B results in more of Y during their tenure (y is ratio and I make no assumptions about the distribution).

I cannot do the usual Mann Whitney/Wilcox because the means of Y are very different across countries.  For example, in the US the mean of Y for both A and B winners is approximately 2 whereas in France it is 1.  So I cannot compare the effect of electing A or B on Y without taking into consideration the country of the election.  What is the best way to do this?  Center Y by country or is there a non-parametric test that can handle this?

My hypothesis is that electing candidate B should result in more of Y on average in each country than electing candidate A.

Example of dataset:
[image]

Comment: I have many questions and doubts about the data. Selection: How were "20-40 elections" in each of three countries winnowed to the nine we see here. Classification: How were candidates classified as A or B? Consistency: What does Y measure? Will 'normalizing' scores for each country, give a measure that is comparable across countries? There are different numbers of A's and B's in the countries. Does classification A vs B mean the same thing in all three 'countries'?
Power of test: Most nonparametric tests require more than four our five observations.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think that a two-way non-parametric tests exists for this situation. See:
https://www.researchgate.net/post/Is_there_a_non-parametric_equivalent_of_a_two_way_ANOVA

I think the simplest solution is normalizing your "y" ratios. For inspiration for your code:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43680246/normalize-by-group

Answer (score 0):

Comment continued. The following 'standardization' within countries and resulting two-sample Wilcoxon test is questionable on the grounds already mentioned, and does not use Country as a factor. Even with all that (or because of all that), the test finds no hint of a significant difference between A and B.

```
us = c(2.3, 1.9, 2.5)
z.us = (us - mean(us))/sd(us)
fr = c(.25, .76, .45)
z.fr = (fr - mean(fr))/sd(fr)
uk = c(.98,1.2,1.1)
z.uk =(uk-mean(uk))/sd(uk)
z = c(z.us, z.fr, z.uk)
ab = c(1,2,1,1,2,2,1,1,2)
cbind(z,ab)
                z ab
 [1,]  0.21821789  1
 [2,] -1.09108945  2
 [3,]  0.87287156  1
 [4,] -0.92099121  1
 [5,]  1.06367998  2
 [6,] -0.14268878  2
 [7,] -1.02888681  1
 [8,]  0.96836405  1
 [9,]  0.06052275  2
wilcox.test(z~ab)

        Wilcoxon rank sum test

data:  z by ab
W = 11, p-value = 0.9048
alternative hypothesis: 
 true location shift is not equal to 0

stripchart(z ~ ab, pch=19, ylim=c(.5,2.5))
```

[image]

Comment: Apologies, the example dataset above was made up as a reduced version of the dataset to illustrate how it was structured.  But thank you for the suggestion and code, going to just standardize the Y values as that makes the most sense.